# What is the best practice to deal with the requests race in js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

I have an AngularJS application which saves the data entered by the user every time when one of the fields on the form has changed. It's a simple post request to the API but with large data set. The way it's implemented at the moment can lead to errors when user changes the data quickly (i.e. double clicking the checkbox), the first request (R1) and the second request (R2) are sent to the server almost at the same time. This might result in R2 being saved before R1 in which case the data on the screen is not what's in the database. I was thinking about queuing the requests in js so that R2 has to wait for R1 to finish, but I wonder if there is any other/better solution to deal with this kind of issue?

Comment: or you could disable the UI which triggers the request while it's in progress. Or you could try and cancel the first request.

Comment: At the very least add a time stamp or honour the `Date` HTTP header set by the client and discard data that has been sent before the last known update. Maybe  monotonically number each request.

Comment: Disabling is not an option in this case (requirements). Cancelling can theoretically be a solution - I'll have to test it. Thanks ADyson.
Deceze, I assume you're suggesting doing that on the API side? The whole process is a lot more complex than I described so I have to check if I could implement some generic solution for that. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Why can't you disable it? Seems like an odd requirement...whats the justification? If you want to stop duplicate requests then it would help a lot. You can easily enable it again when the request ends.